# How to set a UISegmentedControl and SwiftUI shape to the same color?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I have created a RoundedRectangle and set its foregroundColor to blue

`RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.blue)`

I have created a custom SegmentedControl struct and set its color to blue

`UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .blue`

However, the objects render as [totally different shades of blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SbSv.png). How can I set them to the same blue color?

Full code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var choice = Choice.a

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Menu { } label: {
        Text("Menu")
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .padding(5)
          .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
              .foregroundColor(.blue)
          )
      }
      SegmentedControl(choice: $choice)
        .padding(.horizontal, 50)
    }
  }
}

struct SegmentedControl: View {
  @Binding var choice: Choice
  var choices = [Choice.a, Choice.b]
  
  init(choice: Binding<Choice>) {
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .blue
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    self._choice = choice
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Picker("Which tab?",
           selection: $choice,
           content: {
      ForEach(choices, id: \.self) {
        Text($0.description())
      }
    })
      .pickerStyle(.segmented)
  }
}

enum Choice {
  case a
  case b
  
  func description() -> String {
    var str = ""
    switch self {
    case .a:
      str = "Choice A"
    case .b:
      str = "Choice B"
    }
    return str
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `Color.blue` uses `UIColor.systemBlue`

So you can approach it two ways

First, you can change the rectangle

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.blue))
```

Or second change the control

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .systemBlue
```

Either of these changes will match the other. It depends which you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could create a 'Color Set' in the assets and then call your Color like that :

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(Color("the name of your Color"))

UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = Color("the same Color")
```